# How to get Serilog into Azure Log Stream in Azure Function .NET 3.1

Tags: azure-functions, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am able to get the Serilog into console, but after publishing into Azure Functions, the logs message using `Serilog.log.information()` etc does not appear.

I tried writing to a file using file.sink

```
.WriteTo.File(
         @"D:\home\LogFiles\Application\myapp.txt",
        fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_000_000,
        rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
        shared: true,
        flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
```

Below is the configuration I have in the startup.cs

```
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(sp => new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true));

            builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

`WriteTo.Console()` will only print write log events to the Windows Console. But if we publish it to azure, We will not see the console logs.

If you want to use ***Serilog*** into azure. We need to use the package for serilog logs into azure using [Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile) or you can use the [Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights#serilogsinksapplicationinsights) Use kudu to see the log file.

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
    builder.Services.AddLogging(lb => lb.AddSerilog(logger));
```

Refer [here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629489/serilog-with-api-app-in-azure)

Comment: Thank you! I have explorerd the logging into file and Azure Application Insight. May I check how can I enable diagnostic logs for Azure Function App?

Comment: I have updated the answer and check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55254625/15997690) azure functions not support the diagnostics logs. **Application insights** is a better choice for monitoring azure function. If you are using **serilog** you can use kudu console to view the log.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT [Serilog.Sings.RollingFile](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile) is also deprecated. [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file) is recommended